# Scrolling in ListView makes TouchableOpacity unresponsive

Tags: listview, react-native, touchableopacity

We have a ListView with some entries (in our testcase 205 entries) and when you scroll through the List quickly the JS Thread fps sometimes drop from 60 to about 20 and then the TouchableOpacity element will get unresponsive (like all other React Elements). UI Thread fps stay at 60 and scrolling through the list ist Still possible but it takes some time for the Touchable to get responsive again.

It looks like react is creating some kind of queue for events and the scrolling adds events to it, and the touch event on the Touchable has to wait for all the other "unimportant" events to get processed.

We are using React version 15.4.2 and React-Native version 0.40.0.

We can reproduce the problem nearly constantly on a LG Nexus 5X and on a Samsung Note 4, unfortunately not in the emulator (x86 seems to run to fast and arm to slow).

This is the test component where we can reproduce the problem.

```
import * as React from 'react';
import {View, Text, TouchableOpacity, ListView} from 'react-native';

export const SPACING = {
    TINY: 4,
    SMALLER: 8,
    SMALL: 12,
    BASE: 16,
    LARGE: 24,
    XLARGE: 32,
    XXLARGE: 48
};

export const DEFAULT_COLORS = {
    'Accent': '#AF8DE9',
    'NaviBg': '#28222D',
    'SecondaryContainer': '#574c68',
    'SecondaryContainerHeader': '#41384e',
    'Header': '#F5F5F5', // should be #fcfcfc but doesn't work with react-native!???
    'Tabs': '#FCFCFC',
    'Handle': '#AF8DE9',
    'Content': '#FFFFFF',
    'Primary': '#D6AFEB',
    'Green': '#72D2B4',
    'Red': '#E68585',
    'Yellow': '#FABC74',
    'Male': '#9EC6E6',
    'Female': '#EDACC9',
    'Darker': '#3F3F3F',
    'Dark': '#5C5C5C',
    'Normal': '#757575',
    'Light': '#949494',
    'Lighter': '#C2C2C2',
    'LineDivider': '#f3f1f6'
};

const data = '{"Flirt":[{"key":"FLIRT.Flirt","channel":{"channelName":"Flirt","channelMetadata":{"userCount":54}}},{"key":"FLIRT.Ladies only","channel":{"channelName":"Ladies only","channelMetadata":{"userCount":45}}},{"key":"FLIRT.Psssst","channel":{"channelName":"Psssst","channelMetadata":{"userCount":68}}},{"key":"FLIRT.Singles 15-17","channel":{"channelName":"Singles 15-17","channelMetadata":{"userCount":48}}},{"key":"FLIRT.Flirt Private","channel":{"channelName":"Flirt Private","channelMetadata":{"userCount":63}}},{"key":"FLIRT.Flirt 18+","channel":{"channelName":"Flirt 18+","channelMetadata":{"userCount":35}}},{"key":"FLIRT.Flirt 30+","channel":{"channelName":"Flirt 30+","channelMetadata":{"userCount":39}}},{"key":"FLIRT.Videoflirt","channel":{"channelName":"Videoflirt","channelMetadata":{"userCount":22}}},{"key":"FLIRT.Private 23+","channel":{"channelName":"Private 23+","channelMetadata":{"userCount":47}}},{"key":"FLIRT.Suche","channel":{"channelName":"Suche","channelMetadata":{"userCount":43}}}],"Classic":[{"key":"CLASSIC.Nostalgie","channel":{"channelName":"Nostalgie","channelMetadata":{"userCount":4}}},{"key":"CLASSIC.Kiss","channel":{"channelName":"Kiss","channelMetadata":{"userCount":6}}},{"key":"CLASSIC.Welcome!","channel":{"channelName":"Welcome!","channelMetadata":{"userCount":3}}},{"key":"CLASSIC.Family","channel":{"channelName":"Family","channelMetadata":{"userCount":1}}},{"key":"CLASSIC.Knuddels","channel":{"channelName":"Knuddels","channelMetadata":{"userCount":2}}},{"key":"CLASSIC.Classic","channel":{"channelName":"Classic","channelMetadata":{"userCount":1}}},{"key":"CLASSIC.Stammis","channel":{"channelName":"Stammis","channelMetadata":{"userCount":1}}},{"key":"CLASSIC.Mix Classic","channel":{"channelName":"Mix Classic","channelMetadata":{"userCount":1}}},{"key":"CLASSIC.Neustammis","channel":{"channelName":"Neustammis","channelMetadata":{"userCount":1}}},{"key":"CLASSIC.CMs","channel":{"channelName":"CMs","channelMetadata":{"userCount":1}}}],"Spiele":[{"key":"GAMES.Mafia2 Party","channel":{"channelName":"Mafia2 Party","channelMetadata":{"userCount":26}}},{"key":"GAMES.8-Ball","channel":{"channelName":"8-Ball","channelMetadata":{"userCount":19}}},{"key":"GAMES.Mafia2 Vampir","channel":{"channelName":"Mafia2 Vampir","channelMetadata":{"userCount":14}}},{"key":"GAMES.MauMau Kurzturnier Anmeldung","channel":{"channelName":"MauMau Kurzturnier Anmeldung","channelMetadata":{"userCount":14}}},{"key":"GAMES.Fifty! Free","channel":{"channelName":"Fifty! Free","channelMetadata":{"userCount":11}}},{"key":"GAMES.FotoContest Mixed","channel":{"channelName":"FotoContest Mixed","channelMetadata":{"userCount":6}}},{"key":"GAMES.MauMauX 6max","channel":{"channelName":"MauMauX 6max","channelMetadata":{"userCount":6}}},{"key":"GAMES.Poker Knuddels Freeroll","channel":{"channelName":"Poker Knuddels Freeroll","channelMetadata":{"userCount":9}}},{"key":"GAMES.Poker Stundenfinale","channel":{"channelName":"Poker Stundenfinale","channelMetadata":{"userCount":9}}},{"key":"GAMES.SmileyWars","channel":{"channelName":"SmileyWars","channelMetadata":{"userCount":4}}}],"Kartenspiele":[{"key":"CARDGAMES.MauMau Kurzturnier","channel":{"channelName":"MauMau Kurzturnier","channelMetadata":{"userCount":1}}},{"key":"CARDGAMES.Poker Tourneys Stundenfinale","channel":{"channelName":"Poker Tourneys Stundenfinale","channelMetadata":{"userCount":1}}},{"key":"CARDGAMES.MauMau Kurzturnier Anmeldung","channel":{"channelName":"MauMau Kurzturnier Anmeldung","channelMetadata":{"userCount":14}}},{"key":"CARDGAMES.Poker Tourneys","channel":{"channelName":"Poker Tourneys","channelMetadata":{"userCount":1}}},{"key":"CARDGAMES.MauMauX 6max","channel":{"channelName":"MauMauX 6max","channelMetadata":{"userCount":6}}},{"key":"CARDGAMES.Poker Knuddels Freeroll","channel":{"channelName":"Poker Knuddels Freeroll","channelMetadata":{"userCount":9}}},{"key":"CARDGAMES.Poker Stundenfinale","channel":{"channelName":"Poker Stundenfinale","channelMetadata":{"userCount":9}}},{"key":"CA' +
'RDGAMES.Poker 2Kn","channel":{"channelName":"Poker 2Kn","channelMetadata":{"userCount":9}}},{"key":"CARDGAMES.Poker Lobby","channel":{"channelName":"Poker Lobby","channelMetadata":{"userCount":6}}},{"key":"CARDGAMES.Poker 50Kn","channel":{"channelName":"Poker 50Kn","channelMetadata":{"userCount":7}}}],"Lokalrunde":[{"key":"LOKALRUNDE.Karlsruhe","channel":{"channelName":"Karlsruhe","channelMetadata":{"userCount":11}}},{"key":"LOKALRUNDE.Mannheim","channel":{"channelName":"Mannheim","channelMetadata":{"userCount":31}}},{"key":"LOKALRUNDE.Freiburg","channel":{"channelName":"Freiburg","channelMetadata":{"userCount":13}}},{"key":"LOKALRUNDE.BaWü 40+","channel":{"channelName":"BaWü 40+","channelMetadata":{"userCount":11}}},{"key":"LOKALRUNDE.Hamburg","channel":{"channelName":"Hamburg","channelMetadata":{"userCount":43}}},{"key":"LOKALRUNDE.Berlin","channel":{"channelName":"Berlin","channelMetadata":{"userCount":35}}},{"key":"LOKALRUNDE.Bremen","channel":{"channelName":"Bremen","channelMetadata":{"userCount":38}}},{"key":"LOKALRUNDE.Dortmund","channel":{"channelName":"Dortmund","channelMetadata":{"userCount":33}}},{"key":"LOKALRUNDE.Essen","channel":{"channelName":"Essen","channelMetadata":{"userCount":28}}},{"key":"LOKALRUNDE.Köln","channel":{"channelName":"Köln","channelMetadata":{"userCount":28}}}],"Musik":[{"key":"MUSIC.Emo","channel":{"channelName":"Emo","channelMetadata":{"userCount":25}}},{"key":"MUSIC.Alternative","channel":{"channelName":"Alternative","channelMetadata":{"userCount":17}}},{"key":"MUSIC.Hip Hop","channel":{"channelName":"Hip Hop","channelMetadata":{"userCount":15}}},{"key":"MUSIC.Gothic","channel":{"channelName":"Gothic","channelMetadata":{"userCount":10}}},{"key":"MUSIC.Metal","channel":{"channelName":"Metal","channelMetadata":{"userCount":3}}},{"key":"MUSIC.Punk","channel":{"channelName":"Punk","channelMetadata":{"userCount":3}}},{"key":"MUSIC./Sunshine Live","channel":{"channelName":"/Sunshine Live","channelMetadata":{"userCount":3}}},{"key":"MUSIC.Techno","channel":{"channelName":"Techno","channelMetadata":{"userCount":1}}},{"key":"MUSIC.Rap","channel":{"channelName":"Rap","channelMetadata":{"userCount":2}}},{"key":"MUSIC.RnB","channel":{"channelName":"RnB","channelMetadata":{"userCount":1}}}],"Nutzerchannel":[{"key":"MYCHANNELS./Sidoh","channel":{"channelName":"/Sidoh","channelMetadata":{"userCount":34}}},{"key":"MYCHANNELS./DiceOne","channel":{"channelName":"/DiceOne","channelMetadata":{"userCount":27}}},{"key":"MYCHANNELS./Multigame","channel":{"channelName":"/Multigame","channelMetadata":{"userCount":14}}},{"key":"MYCHANNELS./ParaDICE","channel":{"channelName":"/ParaDICE","channelMetadata":{"userCount":14}}},{"key":"MYCHANNELS./Kissecke","channel":{"channelName":"/Kissecke","channelMetadata":{"userCount":8}}},{"key":"MYCHANNELS./Knuddels Area DeLuXe","channel":{"channelName":"/Knuddels Area DeLuXe","channelMetadata":{"userCount":7}}},{"key":"MYCHANNELS./Endless Video","channel":{"channelName":"/Endless Video","channelMetadata":{"userCount":4}}},{"key":"MYCHANNELS./TigerDice","channel":{"channelName":"/TigerDice","channelMetadata":{"userCount":9}}},{"key":"MYCHANNELS./Luk<3s","channel":{"channelName":"/Luk<3s","channelMetadata":{"userCount":4}}},{"key":"MYCHANNELS./Elite-Dice","channel":{"channelName":"/Elite-Dice","channelMetadata":{"userCount":6}}}],"Über 20":[{"key":"OVER20.Mamas&Papas","channel":{"channelName":"Mamas&Papas","channelMetadata":{"userCount":38}}},{"key":"OVER20.Flirt 18+","channel":{"channelName":"Flirt 18+","channelMetadata":{"userCount":35}}},{"key":"OVER20.Flirt 30+","channel":{"channelName":"Flirt 30+","channelMetadata":{"userCount":39}}},{"key":"OVER20.Private 23+","channel":{"channelName":"Private 23+","channelMetadata":{"userCount":47}}},{"key":"OVER20.Private","channel":{"channelName":"Private","channelMetadata":{"userCount":62}}},{"key":"OVER20.Suche","channel":{"channelName":"Suche","channelMetadata":{"userCount":43}}},{"key":"OVER20.Flirt 65+","channel":{"channelName":"Flirt' +
' 65+","channelMetadata":{"userCount":40}}},{"key":"OVER20.Flirt 35+","channel":{"channelName":"Flirt 35+","channelMetadata":{"userCount":41}}},{"key":"OVER20.Flirt 60+","channel":{"channelName":"Flirt 60+","channelMetadata":{"userCount":33}}},{"key":"OVER20.Flirt 40+","channel":{"channelName":"Flirt 40+","channelMetadata":{"userCount":36}}}],"Sport":[{"key":"SPORT.Fußball","channel":{"channelName":"Fußball","channelMetadata":{"userCount":2}}},{"key":"SPORT.Basketball","channel":{"channelName":"Basketball","channelMetadata":{"userCount":2}}},{"key":"SPORT./1895","channel":{"channelName":"/1895","channelMetadata":{"userCount":3}}},{"key":"SPORT.Frankfurt Fußball","channel":{"channelName":"Frankfurt Fußball","channelMetadata":{"userCount":2}}},{"key":"SPORT.Volleyball","channel":{"channelName":"Volleyball","channelMetadata":{"userCount":1}}},{"key":"SPORT.Biker","channel":{"channelName":"Biker","channelMetadata":{"userCount":1}}},{"key":"SPORT.Eishockey","channel":{"channelName":"Eishockey","channelMetadata":{"userCount":1}}},{"key":"SPORT.München Fußball","channel":{"channelName":"München Fußball","channelMetadata":{"userCount":1}}},{"key":"SPORT.Cars","channel":{"channelName":"Cars","channelMetadata":{"userCount":2}}},{"key":"SPORT.Handball","channel":{"channelName":"Handball","channelMetadata":{"userCount":1}}}],"Thementalk":[{"key":"THEMETALK.Coming Out","channel":{"channelName":"Coming Out","channelMetadata":{"userCount":34}}},{"key":"THEMETALK.Emo","channel":{"channelName":"Emo","channelMetadata":{"userCount":25}}},{"key":"THEMETALK.Alternative","channel":{"channelName":"Alternative","channelMetadata":{"userCount":17}}},{"key":"THEMETALK.Hip Hop","channel":{"channelName":"Hip Hop","channelMetadata":{"userCount":15}}},{"key":"THEMETALK.Gothic","channel":{"channelName":"Gothic","channelMetadata":{"userCount":10}}},{"key":"THEMETALK.Rollenspiele","channel":{"channelName":"Rollenspiele","channelMetadata":{"userCount":11}}},{"key":"THEMETALK.Bruchtal","channel":{"channelName":"Bruchtal","channelMetadata":{"userCount":5}}},{"key":"THEMETALK.Mobile Flirt","channel":{"channelName":"Mobile Flirt","channelMetadata":{"userCount":8}}},{"key":"THEMETALK.Mobile Talk","channel":{"channelName":"Mobile Talk","channelMetadata":{"userCount":7}}},{"key":"THEMETALK.Manga & Anime","channel":{"channelName":"Manga & Anime","channelMetadata":{"userCount":4}}}],"Unter 18":[{"key":"UNDER18.Singles 15-17","channel":{"channelName":"Singles 15-17","channelMetadata":{"userCount":48}}},{"key":"UNDER18.Kunterbunt","channel":{"channelName":"Kunterbunt","channelMetadata":{"userCount":29}}},{"key":"UNDER18.Private 15-17","channel":{"channelName":"Private 15-17","channelMetadata":{"userCount":10}}},{"key":"UNDER18.Friends","channel":{"channelName":"Friends","channelMetadata":{"userCount":7}}},{"key":"UNDER18.Flirt 16+","channel":{"channelName":"Flirt 16+","channelMetadata":{"userCount":4}}},{"key":"UNDER18.Kuschelecke","channel":{"channelName":"Kuschelecke","channelMetadata":{"userCount":2}}},{"key":"UNDER18.Friends 15-17","channel":{"channelName":"Friends 15-17","channelMetadata":{"userCount":1}}},{"key":"UNDER18.Teenflirt","channel":{"channelName":"Teenflirt","channelMetadata":{"userCount":1}}},{"key":"UNDER18.Love","channel":{"channelName":"Love","channelMetadata":{"userCount":1}}},{"key":"UNDER18.After School","channel":{"channelName":"After School","channelMetadata":{"userCount":1}}}],"Spaß":[{"key":"FUN.Lokschuppen","channel":{"channelName":"Lokschuppen","channelMetadata":{"userCount":6}}},{"key":"FUN./Video what ever x3","channel":{"channelName":"/Video what ever x3","channelMetadata":{"userCount":6}}},{"key":"FUN.Chinatown","channel":{"channelName":"Chinatown","channelMetadata":{"userCount":2}}},{"key":"FUN.Welcome!","channel":{"channelName":"Welcome!","channelMetadata":{"userCount":3}}},{"key":"FUN./DiceChampion2","channel":{"channelName":"/DiceChampion2","channelMetadata":{"userCount":1}}},{"key":"FUN.Irrenhaus","channel":{"channelName":"Irrenhaus","' +
'channelMetadata":{"userCount":1}}},{"key":"FUN.Pferdegeflüster","channel":{"channelName":"Pferdegeflüster","channelMetadata":{"userCount":1}}},{"key":"FUN.Kekse","channel":{"channelName":"Kekse","channelMetadata":{"userCount":1}}},{"key":"FUN./Chillerbox","channel":{"channelName":"/Chillerbox","channelMetadata":{"userCount":1}}},{"key":"FUN.0-8-15","channel":{"channelName":"0-8-15","channelMetadata":{"userCount":1}}}],"Liebe":[{"key":"LOVE.Coming Out","channel":{"channelName":"Coming Out","channelMetadata":{"userCount":34}}},{"key":"LOVE.Liebeskummer","channel":{"channelName":"Liebeskummer","channelMetadata":{"userCount":1}}},{"key":"LOVE.Herzschmerz","channel":{"channelName":"Herzschmerz","channelMetadata":{"userCount":1}}},{"key":"LOVE.Liebe","channel":{"channelName":"Liebe","channelMetadata":{"userCount":1}}},{"key":"LOVE./Betreten auf eigene Gefahr","channel":{"channelName":"/Betreten auf eigene Gefahr","channelMetadata":{"userCount":1}}},{"key":"LOVE./shut up","channel":{"channelName":"/shut up","channelMetadata":{"userCount":1}}},{"key":"LOVE./Hollywoodliebe","channel":{"channelName":"/Hollywoodliebe","channelMetadata":{"userCount":1}}},{"key":"LOVE./Ein Hoch auf Uns","channel":{"channelName":"/Ein Hoch auf Uns","channelMetadata":{"userCount":1}}},{"key":"LOVE./kisshall","channel":{"channelName":"/kisshall","channelMetadata":{"userCount":1}}},{"key":"LOVE./Sternmensch","channel":{"channelName":"/Sternmensch","channelMetadata":{"userCount":1}}}],"Schule & Beruf":[{"key":"JOB./Web-Dev","channel":{"channelName":"/Web-Dev","channelMetadata":{"userCount":2}}},{"key":"JOB.Hausaufgaben","channel":{"channelName":"Hausaufgaben","channelMetadata":{"userCount":1}}},{"key":"JOB.Kaffeepause","channel":{"channelName":"Kaffeepause","channelMetadata":{"userCount":5}}},{"key":"JOB.Campus","channel":{"channelName":"Campus","channelMetadata":{"userCount":1}}},{"key":"JOB.Hitzefrei","channel":{"channelName":"Hitzefrei","channelMetadata":{"userCount":1}}},{"key":"JOB./Hausaufgaben Video","channel":{"channelName":"/Hausaufgaben Video","channelMetadata":{"userCount":1}}}],"Fantasie":[{"key":"PHANTASY.Rollenspiele","channel":{"channelName":"Rollenspiele","channelMetadata":{"userCount":11}}},{"key":"PHANTASY.Bruchtal","channel":{"channelName":"Bruchtal","channelMetadata":{"userCount":5}}},{"key":"PHANTASY.Manga & Anime","channel":{"channelName":"Manga & Anime","channelMetadata":{"userCount":4}}},{"key":"PHANTASY.Vampire","channel":{"channelName":"Vampire","channelMetadata":{"userCount":3}}},{"key":"PHANTASY.Magic","channel":{"channelName":"Magic","channelMetadata":{"userCount":2}}},{"key":"PHANTASY.Nirvana","channel":{"channelName":"Nirvana","channelMetadata":{"userCount":1}}},{"key":"PHANTASY./Schneezone","channel":{"channelName":"/Schneezone","channelMetadata":{"userCount":1}}},{"key":"PHANTASY./Einhornwinterwonderland","channel":{"channelName":"/Einhornwinterwonderland","channelMetadata":{"userCount":1}}},{"key":"PHANTASY./only god forgives","channel":{"channelName":"/only god forgives","channelMetadata":{"userCount":1}}},{"key":"PHANTASY./Gedöns","channel":{"channelName":"/Gedöns","channelMetadata":{"userCount":1}}}],"Unterhaltung":[{"key":"ENTERTAINMENT.Video Chill-Out","channel":{"channelName":"Video Chill-Out","channelMetadata":{"userCount":11}}},{"key":"ENTERTAINMENT.Mobile Flirt","channel":{"channelName":"Mobile Flirt","channelMetadata":{"userCount":8}}},{"key":"ENTERTAINMENT.Mobile Talk","channel":{"channelName":"Mobile Talk","channelMetadata":{"userCount":7}}},{"key":"ENTERTAINMENT.Computer Talk","channel":{"channelName":"Computer Talk","channelMetadata":{"userCount":3}}},{"key":"ENTERTAINMENT./Vegas Dice","channel":{"channelName":"/Vegas Dice","channelMetadata":{"userCount":3}}},{"key":"ENTERTAINMENT./Russia","channel":{"channelName":"/Russia","channelMetadata":{"userCount":2}}},{"key":"ENTERTAINMENT.Mode","channel":{"channelName":"Mode","channelMetadata":{"userCount":3}}},{"key":"ENTERTAINMENT./Strawberries","channel":{"channelName"' +
':"/Strawberries","channelMetadata":{"userCount":3}}},{"key":"ENTERTAINMENT.Videogames","channel":{"channelName":"Videogames","channelMetadata":{"userCount":1}}},{"key":"ENTERTAINMENT.Video Party","channel":{"channelName":"Video Party","channelMetadata":{"userCount":1}}}],"Freizeit":[{"key":"HOBBY.Plauderecke","channel":{"channelName":"Plauderecke","channelMetadata":{"userCount":6}}},{"key":"HOBBY./Video Denny","channel":{"channelName":"/Video Denny","channelMetadata":{"userCount":1}}},{"key":"HOBBY./Lion49","channel":{"channelName":"/Lion49","channelMetadata":{"userCount":3}}},{"key":"HOBBY.Biergarten","channel":{"channelName":"Biergarten","channelMetadata":{"userCount":2}}},{"key":"HOBBY./what ever x3","channel":{"channelName":"/what ever x3","channelMetadata":{"userCount":1}}},{"key":"HOBBY.Forumstreff","channel":{"channelName":"Forumstreff","channelMetadata":{"userCount":1}}},{"key":"HOBBY.Party","channel":{"channelName":"Party","channelMetadata":{"userCount":1}}},{"key":"HOBBY.Weihnachtsmarkt","channel":{"channelName":"Weihnachtsmarkt","channelMetadata":{"userCount":2}}},{"key":"HOBBY.Chattertreffen","channel":{"channelName":"Chattertreffen","channelMetadata":{"userCount":1}}},{"key":"HOBBY./Italien","channel":{"channelName":"/Italien","channelMetadata":{"userCount":1}}}],"Videochat":[{"key":"VIDEOCHAT.Videoflirt","channel":{"channelName":"Videoflirt","channelMetadata":{"userCount":22}}},{"key":"VIDEOCHAT.Video Chill-Out","channel":{"channelName":"Video Chill-Out","channelMetadata":{"userCount":11}}},{"key":"VIDEOCHAT./Knuddels Area DeLuXe","channel":{"channelName":"/Knuddels Area DeLuXe","channelMetadata":{"userCount":7}}},{"key":"VIDEOCHAT./Endless Video","channel":{"channelName":"/Endless Video","channelMetadata":{"userCount":4}}},{"key":"VIDEOCHAT./Video what ever x3","channel":{"channelName":"/Video what ever x3","channelMetadata":{"userCount":6}}},{"key":"VIDEOCHAT./die lockererunde","channel":{"channelName":"/die lockererunde","channelMetadata":{"userCount":3}}},{"key":"VIDEOCHAT./Vegas Dice","channel":{"channelName":"/Vegas Dice","channelMetadata":{"userCount":3}}},{"key":"VIDEOCHAT./Frankfurt Video","channel":{"channelName":"/Frankfurt Video","channelMetadata":{"userCount":2}}},{"key":"VIDEOCHAT./Yanx","channel":{"channelName":"/Yanx","channelMetadata":{"userCount":3}}},{"key":"VIDEOCHAT./AdventureTime","channel":{"channelName":"/AdventureTime","channelMetadata":{"userCount":2}}}],"Channels mit Apps":[{"key":"APPCHANNELS./DiceOne","channel":{"channelName":"/DiceOne","channelMetadata":{"userCount":27}}},{"key":"APPCHANNELS./Multigame","channel":{"channelName":"/Multigame","channelMetadata":{"userCount":14}}},{"key":"APPCHANNELS./Braintainment","channel":{"channelName":"/Braintainment","channelMetadata":{"userCount":3}}},{"key":"APPCHANNELS./777","channel":{"channelName":"/777","channelMetadata":{"userCount":4}}},{"key":"APPCHANNELS./Wahrsagen","channel":{"channelName":"/Wahrsagen","channelMetadata":{"userCount":2}}},{"key":"APPCHANNELS./Lie6e","channel":{"channelName":"/Lie6e","channelMetadata":{"userCount":1}}},{"key":"APPCHANNELS./GötterDice x3","channel":{"channelName":"/GötterDice x3","channelMetadata":{"userCount":1}}},{"key":"APPCHANNELS./Schiffe versenken","channel":{"channelName":"/Schiffe versenken","channelMetadata":{"userCount":1}}},{"key":"APPCHANNELS./Spielkasino","channel":{"channelName":"/Spielkasino","channelMetadata":{"userCount":1}}},{"key":"APPCHANNELS./norbyte","channel":{"channelName":"/norbyte","channelMetadata":{"userCount":1}}}]}';


export default class PerformanceTest extends React.Component<any,any> {
    private listEntries: any = JSON.parse(data);
    private ds = new ListView.DataSource({
        rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) =>
        r1 !== r2,
        sectionHeaderHasChanged: (s1, s2) =>
        s1 !== s2
    });

    constructor(props: any) {
        super(props);
    }

    render() {
        const newDS = this.ds.cloneWithRowsAndSections(this.listEntries);
        return (
            <View style={{flexDirection:'column', alignItems:'stretch', flex:1}}>
                <TouchableOpacity style={{height: 50, backgroundColor: 'skyblue'}} onPress={() => console.log("Click")}>
                    <Text>Test</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
                <ListView
                    initialListSize={1000}
                    dataSource={newDS}
                    pageSize={10}
                    renderRow={
                        (c:any,index:number) => {
                            return (
                                <View key={c.key} style={{flexDirection:'row', flex:1,alignItems:'center', marginHorizontal: SPACING.LARGE}}>
                                    <View style={{width: 32, height: 32, backgroundColor:DEFAULT_COLORS.Green}}/>
                                    <View style={{flexDirection:'column', flex:1, paddingLeft:SPACING.SMALL}}>
                                        <View
                                            style={{flexDirection:'row', paddingTop:SPACING.SMALLER + SPACING.TINY, paddingBottom:SPACING.TINY + SPACING.SMALLER}}>
                                            <Text numberOfLines={1} style={{flex:1, paddingLeft: SPACING.TINY}}>
                                                {c.channel.channelName}
                                            </Text>
                                            <Text style={{flex: 1, paddingLeft: SPACING.SMALL}}>{c.channel.channelMetadata.userCount}</Text>
                                        </View>
                                        {this.props.hasSeparator &&
                                        <View style={{
                                                    height: 1,
                                                    backgroundColor: DEFAULT_COLORS.LineDivider,
                                                    borderRadius:3}}/>
                                        }
                                    </View>
                                </View>
                            )
                        }
                    }
                    renderSectionHeader={
                    (data: any, category:any) => {
                        return (<Text>{category}</Text>);
                    }
                }>
                </ListView>
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

Any ideas or help would be appreciated.
Thank you

Comment: I just tried with a 400 rows ListView (RN 0.38.2) and you're correct, the framerate drops and the buttons take sometime to respond.